# Does jQuery have built in full support for JSON2?

Tags: jquery, json

I see there are 2 questions just like this, but they refer to older versions (<= 1.3)

I wanted to get an update on this because there were indications it may be built in. Bottom line: Do I need to include json2.js in my main library file along with jQuery ~1.6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to include `json2.js`, for example if you use methods such as `JSON.stringify` (this method is built into modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you need to include it in addition to jQuery).

Comment: Just to add, `json2.js` only defines the [additional] methods on the `JSON` object if they don't already exist, so it doesn't stomp on the browser's implementation if the browser provides support for JSON. What I'm getting at is that is doesn't hurt to always include it.

Answer (score 0):

for older browsers yes you'll have to include it but modern browsers dont need it ...